# in what sense is "make up" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I found this on NYTimes:

"‘one fine morning’ review: the moments that make up a rich life"

how do I interpret make up in this context?

Comment: I think all the moments built the good life. (establishment)

Answer (score 3):

Sense 1 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=make_up&rdfrom=Make%20up#Verb): "To constitute the components of a whole".